# Scheduling a Task to Run Indefinitely

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I suppose what I want is closer to a service, but I'd like to know if I could just accomplish this with a scheduled task.

I can create a task with these parameters:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 7am -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepetitionDuration ([timespan]::MaxValue)
```

But if the computer boots up after 7 AM the task never fires right?

How can I have a task that repeats every 5 mins no matter the time when the computer is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `-Once -At` you could be using [`-AtStartup`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.630).aspx) or [`-AtLogon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.630).aspx)

<kbd>-AtStartup</kbd>

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepetitionDuration ([timespan]::MaxValue)
```

<kbd>-AtLogon</kbd>

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepetitionDuration ([timespan]::MaxValue)
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't think Atlogon supported repetitioninterval. When I run that command I get this error: New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Comment: -1.  `AtStartup` does not support `RepetitionInterval`. @red888 what did you end up using as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method to achieve the desired result:

```
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$RT = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 7am -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 1)  -RepetitionInterval  (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
$T.Repetition = $RT.Repetition
```

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the -RepetitionDuration it defaults to Indefinite.